# Recover the Deleted files from GIT OR SVN

Tags: git, visual-studio, restore

I had a folder structure with multiple projects in Visual Studio. I committed a few in my old Repo of SVN. And when I added a few more projects, we decided to move to Git.

While creating a new repo in Git and checking in, by mistake, I ran a `Git reset --hard` and it deleted all the files from local.

These files do not exist in either SVN or Git repo.

I tried to restore using the `git fsck --lost-found`, `git show` , `git merge`, `git reflog`. But none of that works. It always shows me the whole list of files in Deleted.

I ran the `git show 4825b63f49cea10539a4c27a6287e195d3d087b2 > 4825b63f49cea10539a4c27a6287e195d3d087b2.txt` after running `git reflog`. And the text file does contain all the files with its code. But I am not able to restore it.

Before I started with Git, the code was connected with SVN but may not be committed.

Is there any way I can restore the code from Git or SVN?

Answer (score 0):

If `4825b63f49cea10539a4c27a6287e195d3d087b2` is a commit, you can try at least

```
cd /path/to/repo
git restore 4825b63f49cea10539a4c27a6287e195d3d087b2 -- .
```

See if the content of that commit is visible then.